# Printing pdf pages in a custom order

Tags: pdf, printing

https://www.flickr.com/photos/198448552@N03/52958761079/in/dateposted-public/

I have a pdf document that has hundreds of pages. Its pages' dimensions are 4.25" (width) x 5.5" (height), so that four of them fit on a single side of an 8.5" x 11" sheet of paper. I wish to take advantage of this by printing four pages to a side, but I would like them to print so that on the front side of the first sheet are pages

2 3

6 7

and on the back side of the first sheet are pages

4 1

8 5

(Please see picture linked above.)

On the second sheet, the pages on the front side of course should go

10 11

14 15

and on the back

12 9

16 13.

And so on. (I desire this because I wish to fold along the vertical line down the middle, then chop the horizontal line across the middle, then bind the papers into a booklet.)

Is there a way to do this without specifying page numbers manually?

I'm using Windows 11.

(I know very little about computers, so please dumb things down as much as possible.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are many applications that can print documents such as a PDF file.
Some applications have *Print* dialogs, such as [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor), below, and [LibreOffice *Writer*](https://www.libreoffice.org/), that can print the file as a *Booklet*.

[image: Booklet Page Order]

*PDF-XChange Editor* and *Writer* also have preview panes, so you can view the page layout.

Comment: Thanks! This is as far as I got with your advice: https://www.flickr.com/photos/198448552@N03/52960478133/in/dateposted-public/.

What might I do to accomplish the four-pages-per-sheet-side printing?

Answer (score 1):

To print the pages of your PDF document in the desired order, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the PDF document using a PDF reader or viewer program on your computer. If you don't have one installed, you can download and install a free PDF reader such as Adobe Acrobat Reader DC or Foxit Reader.
2. Once you have the PDF document open, go to the print settings by clicking on "File" in the menu bar and selecting "Print" or by using the shortcut Ctrl+P.
3. In the print settings window, look for an option called "Page Sizing & Handling" or a similar option that allows you to control the page layout and print multiple pages per sheet. This option may vary depending on the PDF viewer you are using.
4. Within the "Page Sizing & Handling" section, locate the option for
   "Pages per sheet" or "Multiple pages" and select "4" or "Custom" (if
   available).
5. Next, you'll need to configure the page order to achieve the desired layout. Look for an option called "Page Order," "Page Arrangement," or something similar. You'll want to select an option that prints the pages in the following order: 2 3 6 7 on the front side and 4 1 8 5 on the back side of the first sheet, as shown in the picture you provided.
6. Once you have set the desired page order, proceed with printing by clicking on the "Print" or "OK" button.

Note: The exact steps and options may vary depending on the PDF viewer you are using, as different programs have different interfaces. The instructions above are general guidelines, but you may need to explore the print settings in your specific PDF viewer to find the corresponding options.

If you found this helpful please remember to rate it! Cheers!

Comment: I have downloaded Acrobat Reader DC, but I am having trouble following your step 5.